# Unable to Locate Audio Files: How to Resolve?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working with sounds for the first time. When I click the button, the audio specified below should be playing, but I'm getting the print result. When I remove print and complete the function with `player.play()` the program crashes and says "found nil when unwrapping". My sound folder is in the Build Phases - Copy Bundle Resources as well.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var player: AVAudioPlayer!
    
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(sender.currentTitle!)
        playSound()
    }
    
    func playSound() {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "a", withExtension: "wav") {
          player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        } else {
          print("No resouce named A.wav")
        }
        
            /*
             let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "A", withExtension: "mp3")
         player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
             player.play()
             */
        }
}
```

I tried to delete everything and added again but nothing changed. I tried with different file types as well. What might be the problem ?

Comment: What is the filename, "a.wav" or "A.mp3"? Make sure you typed it correctly.

Comment: Your app is not crashing because you removed print(), but because you removed the [Optional Binding](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/thebasics/#Optional-Binding), and the force-unwrap the not existing URL.

Comment: func playSound() {
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "a", withExtension: "mp3")
            player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
            player.play()
        }
the file is a.mp3. ı was using this function on my previous project but in this one it doesn't work.

Comment: You say you do Copy Bundle Resources, but is the file actually there where you expect it? Check your .app bundle in Finder if the mp3 file is inside.

Comment: I moved the files out of the Sounds folder and it works now, but if I put them in a folder, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Bundle` has the Instance Method [`url(forResource:withExtension:subdirectory:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1416712-url) that you can use to point to your sound file resource which is located in a subfolder of your .app bundle.

For example:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "A", withExtension: ".mp3", subdirectory: "Sound")!
```

You have to carefully check that the string in this call match the actual structure, otherwise it will fail (and crash if you force-unwrap).

Comment: Thank you, adding subdirectory solved my problem.